# Gulp tasks not running synchronously

Tags: gulp, bower

I am trying to install packages through bower, and once the installation is finished, I want the files to be moved from dist folder to its parent, and then delete the dist folder. But somehow, its not working properly.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    bower = require('gulp-bower'),
    del = require('del'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    merge = require('merge-stream');
    vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');
    runSequence = require('run-sequence');

var appPath="./www";
var folders = getFolders(appPath);

/* Function to get folders present in www */
function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter(function(file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
      });
}

gulp.task('clean', function (){
    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
       return gulp.src(path.join(appPath, folder))
            .pipe(vinylPaths(del))
    });
});

/* Gulp task to run bower install */
gulp.task('bower', ['clean'], function() {
    return bower({cmd: "install"});

});

/* Gulp task to copy files from dist folder to their parent folders */
gulp.task('moveFiles', ['bower'], function (){
    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
        console.log("FOLDER", folder);
        return gulp.src(path.join(appPath, folder, '/dist/**/*'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(appPath, folder )));

    });
    return tasks;
});

/* Gulp task to clean the dist folder after files have been copied  */
gulp.task('delete-dist-folder', ['moveFiles'], function () {
    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
           return gulp.src(path.join(appPath, folder, '/dist'))
                .pipe(vinylPaths(del))
    });
    return tasks;
});

gulp.task('default', ['delete-dist-folder']);
```

This is what I wrote till now. 
After bower, the rest two tasks don't run. But if I run them individually, they work perfectly fine.

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the `clean` task, you're not returning.If you want to pipe multiple streams you may want to have a look at [`map-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream).

Comment: @MarcoL: thanks for the suggestion. I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is that you return *arrays* of event streams.** Look at your `delete-dist-folder` task. You `return tasks` and `tasks` is created from calling `.map` on an array. So `tasks` is an array (of event streams).

Gulp does not know what to do with your arrays and assumes that your tasks are synchronous. There are only 3 ways to mark a task as asynchronous: 1) return an even stream; Gulp will wait for the stream to end, 2) return a promise; Gulp will wait for the promise to be resolved or rejected, or 3) declare your task callback to take a single parameter which you'll call when your task is done; Gulp will wait for the callback to be called. An array of event streams does not correspond to any of these options.

The Gulp wiki [suggest using `merge-stream`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md) to return more than one stream from a task. Judging by the code of `merge-stream`, and supposing you imported `merge-stream` as `merge`, you could do `return merge.apply(undefined, tasks)`.

Side node: in your `clean` task you forgot to return a value.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue a while back when nesting task(requiring one task in another). So to solve this issue and run task in sequence I used `run-sequence`.

You seem to have installed `run-sequence`. Use it this way:

```
runSequence = require('run-sequence');

    gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
      runSequence('clean', 'bower', 'moveFiles', 'delete-dist-folder',
                 callback);
    });
```

Hope this might help you. You can refer [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) for any help.
This is a temporary solution untill `gulp 4.0`, which will include option to configure your task run in parallel or sequentially.

Comment: I tried this too, but then other than bower, no other task gets executed. The console logs also do not print. Is there anything else that I might be missing?

Comment: Are the `src` correct..? Means do the `src` exist..? Did try loggin `src`..?

Comment: yes... The src is correct, because I see the tasks working properly... If I run like, gulp bower, then gulp moveFiles, then gulp delete-dist-folder, they work flawlessly.